# Rendering PlantUML in Markdown in VscCode Preview and Gitlab

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, vscode-extensions, plantuml

I have the following PlantUML diagram in a markdown file (sample.md):

````
### Sample UML Sequence Diagram

```PlantUML
@startuml UMLSequenceDiagram
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
@enduml
```
![](UMLSequenceDiagram.svg)
````

which renders in VsCode Markdown Preview as this:

#### Sample UML Sequence Diagram

```
@startuml UMLSequenceDiagram
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
@enduml
```

If this sample.md is added to a GitLab repository, the PlantUML diagram rendering is broken in GitLab.
The fix is to change the token of the first line of the script to read like this (all lowercase):

````
```plantuml
````

That does fix the rendering in GitLab but now VsCode Markdown Preview is broken.

Has anyone succeeded to get both renderers working with a single plantuml token?